# Get multiple data from two different while() loops with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Once clicked a button make an ajax consult that's connected to a php file that has the following script:

```
$getserverstream = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM `aportations_servers` WHERE `type` = 'stream'");
while($gotservers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getserverstream))
{
    $serverhost = $gotservers['content'];
    $aaSQLa = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM series_aportations WHERE episodeid = '$artID' and server = '$serverhost' ORDER BY points DESC");
    while($rowQQA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aaSQLa))
    {
        //CODE STUFF

        echo'<tr><td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$weburl.''.$gotservers['icon'].'">'.$gotservers['short'].'</div></td>
                <td><img src="'.$miniflagsdirectory.''.$rowQQA['language'].'">'.$answersub.'</td>                                                               <td>'.$answerquality.'</td>                                                     <td>'.$soundquality.'</td>
                <td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$useraportador['avatarimg'].'"><a href="/profile?user='.$useraportador['id'].'">'.$useraportador['user'].'</a></div></td>
                <td>
                <div class="chip">'.$likes.' likes</div>
                <div class="chip">'.$dislikes.' dislikes</div>
                </td>                                               
                <td><a href="/episodeaport?id='.$rowQQA['id'].'&episodeid='.$artID.'&type=s"><i class="material-icons">fast_forward</i></a></td>
                </tr>';
    }
}


//DOWNLOAD    
$getserverdownload = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM `aportations_servers` WHERE `type` = 'download'");
while($gotserverd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getserverdownload))
{
    $serverhostd = $gotserverd['content'];
    $aaSQLao = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM series_aportations WHERE episodeid = '$artID' and server = '$serverhostd' ORDER BY points DESC");
    while($rowQQAA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aaSQLao))
    {
        //CODE STUFF                                                                                                    
        echo'<tr><td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$weburl.''.$gotserverd['icon'].'">'.$gotserverd['short'].'</div></td>
            <td><img src="'.$miniflagsdirectory.''.$rowQQAA['language'].'">'.$answersubb.'</td>                                                         <td>'.$answerqualityy.'</td>                                                        <td>'.$soundqualityy.'</td>
            <td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$useraportadorr['avatarimg'].'"><a href="/profile?user='.$useraportadorr['id'].'">'.$useraportadorr['user'].'</a></div></td>
            <td>
            <div class="chip">'.$likess.' likes</div>
            <div class="chip">'.$dislikess.' dislikes</div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/episodeaport?id='.$rowQQAA['id'].'&episodeid='.$artID.'&type=s"><i class="material-icons">fast_forward</i></a></td>
            </tr>';
    }
}
```

It outputs the values of two while loops as you can see and I need them to be set as a variable.

This is my js code:

```
$("#linksactivator").click(function() {
        var postid = $("#postid").val();
        var posttype = $("#posttype").val();
        var linksnumber = $("#linksnumber").val();      
        var dataString = 'postid='+postid+'&posttype='+posttype+'&linksnumber='+linksnumber;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            url: "ajax/getlinks.php",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#linksactivator").addClass('disabled');
                $("#activatedlinks").empty();
                $("#activatedlinks").prepend('<i class="material-icons left">access_time</i>CARGANDO...');
            },          
            success: function(data){                                                    
                $("#activatedlinks").empty();
                $("#activatedlinks").prepend('<i class="material-icons left">thumb_up</i>Ver enlaces ('+linksnumber+')');
                $("#activatedlinks").removeClass('disabled');
                $("#aportations-watch").prepend(data);
                $("#aportations-download").prepend(data);

            }
            });                 
        return false;
    });
```

I don't know if its even possible.
PD: I've tried with json creating an array but it just outputs the first response from each loop. I don't know how to put them in an only array to get the response later with the js code. I'd be so grateful with any response :-)

Comment: What do you mean by *"put them in a variable"* or *"get the response later"*?

Comment: I'm sorry if i have not explained well but i'm spanish and my english is not too good: i just want to print the two different "echo" in the the two .prepend data in js script

Comment: Use a translation service if needed or [stackoverflow en espanol](https://es.stackoverflow.com/). Hard to help when we don't understand the problem

Comment: @charlietfl stackoverflow in spanish has not almost users and seldom they help people.

Answer (score 0):

this will give you all the result you want in one array. i am not sure this will help you or not.

```
$data['one'] = array();
$data['two'] = array();
$getserverstream = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM `aportations_servers` WHERE `type` = 'stream'");
while($gotservers = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getserverstream))
{
    $serverhost = $gotservers['content'];
    $aaSQLa = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM series_aportations WHERE episodeid = '$artID' and server = '$serverhost' ORDER BY points DESC");
    while($rowQQA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aaSQLa))
    {
        //CODE STUFF

        $data['one'][] = '<tr><td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$weburl.''.$gotservers['icon'].'">'.$gotservers['short'].'</div></td>
                <td><img src="'.$miniflagsdirectory.''.$rowQQA['language'].'">'.$answersub.'</td>                                                               <td>'.$answerquality.'</td>                                                     <td>'.$soundquality.'</td>
                <td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$useraportador['avatarimg'].'"><a href="/profile?user='.$useraportador['id'].'">'.$useraportador['user'].'</a></div></td>
                <td>
                <div class="chip">'.$likes.' likes</div>
                <div class="chip">'.$dislikes.' dislikes</div>
                </td>                                               
                <td><a href="/episodeaport?id='.$rowQQA['id'].'&episodeid='.$artID.'&type=s"><i class="material-icons">fast_forward</i></a></td>
                </tr>';
    }
}


//DOWNLOAD    
$getserverdownload = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM `aportations_servers` WHERE `type` = 'download'");
while($gotserverd = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getserverdownload))
{
    $serverhostd = $gotserverd['content'];
    $aaSQLao = MYSQL_::Bits("SELECT * FROM series_aportations WHERE episodeid = '$artID' and server = '$serverhostd' ORDER BY points DESC");
    while($rowQQAA = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aaSQLao))
    {
        //CODE STUFF                                                                                                    
        $data['two'][] = '<tr><td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$weburl.''.$gotserverd['icon'].'">'.$gotserverd['short'].'</div></td>
            <td><img src="'.$miniflagsdirectory.''.$rowQQAA['language'].'">'.$answersubb.'</td>                                                         <td>'.$answerqualityy.'</td>                                                        <td>'.$soundqualityy.'</td>
            <td><div class="chip"><img src="'.$useraportadorr['avatarimg'].'"><a href="/profile?user='.$useraportadorr['id'].'">'.$useraportadorr['user'].'</a></div></td>
            <td>
            <div class="chip">'.$likess.' likes</div>
            <div class="chip">'.$dislikess.' dislikes</div>
            </td>
            <td><a href="/episodeaport?id='.$rowQQAA['id'].'&episodeid='.$artID.'&type=s"><i class="material-icons">fast_forward</i></a></td>
            </tr>';
    }
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

The js file

```
$("#linksactivator").click(function() {
        var postid = $("#postid").val();
        var posttype = $("#posttype").val();
        var linksnumber = $("#linksnumber").val();      
        var dataString = 'postid='+postid+'&posttype='+posttype+'&linksnumber='+linksnumber;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'html',
            url: "ajax/getlinks.php",
            data: dataString,
            beforeSend: function() {
                $("#linksactivator").addClass('disabled');
                $("#activatedlinks").empty();
                $("#activatedlinks").prepend('<i class="material-icons left">access_time</i>CARGANDO...');
            },          
            success: function(data){                                                    
                $("#activatedlinks").empty();
                $("#activatedlinks").prepend('<i class="material-icons left">thumb_up</i>Ver enlaces ('+linksnumber+')');
                $("#activatedlinks").removeClass('disabled');
                //here console the data first and prepend it accordingly
                $("#aportations-watch").prepend(data.one);
                $("#aportations-download").prepend(data.two);

            }
            });                 
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Yes but what should i put in the js file then?